# MLPClassifier model accuracy fine tuning with 20000 samples

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network

Input    : 50 deep feature of voice

size     : 20000+ samples

solver   : adam

output classes : 10 ( digit 0 to 9)

hidden layers and neurons : 3 and 100,100,100

Code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Combineddatafeatures,
Combineddatalabels, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam',hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100,100))

clf.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)) 

predicted_values = clf.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score = accuracy_score(y_test,predicted_values)

print(score)
```

Current accuracy : **0.5693142575234337**

How to improve accuracy of samples (20262, 50 shape)  (?) 
by fine-tuning

1. Number of hidden layers
2. Neurons in hidden layers

Answer (score 0):

One way to do parameters tuning is to use the `GridSearchCV` method of sklearn : [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

It will test all the parameters combination you will give and output the best one.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Combineddatafeatures,
Combineddatalabels, test_size=0.1, random_state=1)

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='adam',hidden_layer_sizes=(100,100,100))

params = {
    'hidden_layer_sizes' : [(100, 100, 100), (125, 125, 125)] # Every combination you want to try
}

gscv = GridSearchCV(clf, params, verbose=1)

gscv.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train))
print(gscv.best_params_) 

predicted_values = gscv.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score = accuracy_score(y_test,predicted_values)

print(score)
```

Comment: Any guidelines to decide layers and neurons based on input size and feature set size?

Comment: Usually, I try to reduce gradually the numbers of neurons to get something like (128, 64, 32). What is your output size ?

Comment: 20K samples are input and will get 20K labels after classification

Comment: Sorry I meant the dimension of one label (I assume you are using one hot encoding)!

Comment: 50 is the size . (20262, 50)  is the shape

Comment: Ok so I would try something like (125, 100, 75) with 3 layers. If you are not overfitting, you might want to try with more neurons

Comment: output classes : 10